# Jquery recover value

Tags: php, jquery, load

I use load function of jQuery for call PHP file and get response and for example in the side of PHP I get the value "one".

How I can send this value to jQuery?

**jQuery function load call file :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#file_content").load("index.php?action=ok");

});
```

The jQuery script call index.php and with **action=ok** for active PHP function and for example get the value (in the side of PHP) "start", this value get I want send other time to my function of jQuery and show the value "start" - I get until, into jQuery function.

If value "start" shows, the jQuery function works and if no get this value (start) the jQuery function doesn't work, the problem for me is this value gets in PHP and I don't know how I can detect for works into jQuery.

Comment: Please [accept answers to your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It encourages others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

$.load has a callback function.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#file_content").load("index.php?action=ok", function(data){
    if(data == "start"){
        //your code
    } else {
        //if the response from php is not "start";
    }
});

});
```

Comment: My problem it´s in the php file , i need create string as <?php $start="ok";?> and jquery detect this , because in this file generate more code ..... thank´s

Comment: explicamelo mejor en español xD